# Where is my max-age header coming from?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, cache-control, outputcache

I'm well aware of how I could set it myself, but I am concerned about having it configured in two different places.  To receive the bounty, please tell me where I should look to find the **existing** setting.

Places we've already looked for the existing setting, without success:

- the web.config `<StaticContent>` section
- IIS output caching section, at all three levels:

  - machine
  - site
  - application
- Code (I did a global search for `SetMaxAge`)

## Context

We recently noticed that our CSS and JS files aren't getting refreshed.  When I inspect the network traffic, they are coming back from the server with a header (`Cache-Control: max-age=604800`) that gives them a seven-day lifespan.

We need to reduce the cache lifetime.  But for the life of me I can't find where it is set.

It is *not* set in the web.config `<StaticContent>` section.

It is *not* set in the IIS output caching section (I looked under the machine, the site, and the application-- they are all blank).

It is *not* set in code-- I did a global code search for `SetMaxAge` and got nuthin'.
Where else can I look?

Is it possible it is being set by the gateway or load balancer in our data center?

Comment: Adding a new setting for max age will either override the existing, or provides a duplicate header. Either way, it might tell you a lot about where it's getting set.

Comment: BTW, since the only answer-er was confused about your question, I've put the main question first. I'm hoping for a comprehensive answer, myself.

Comment: Thanks for that... I never did get an answer, and we did a workaround.  But I still want to know, so I'm adding a bounty.

Comment: Did you check web.config at the server and folder (js/css) levels?

Comment: Are there any headers indicating there could be a reverse proxy (X-Cache, Via, etc...). Varnish could do this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this in web config, or you can use IIS ui to change (see link below):

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
       <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"
        cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" /> <!-- 1 day -->
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See more here: https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

IIS documentation states that the default value is 1 day.

Here are some other ways what could have affect these settings:
http://www.galcho.com/blog/post/2008/02/27/IIS7-How-to-set-cache-control-for-static-content.aspx

- overrideModeDefault value in applicationHost.config
- earlier appcmd.exe settings
- or client setting can also override your values.

Comment: I'm not sure adding it like this is the best idea when I don't know where the header is coming from to begin with.  7 days is not the default.  If I add it here, I can't be sure it won't be overridden by whatever mechanism is currently putting it there.

Comment: Where and how are you viewing the headers?

Comment: IIS documentation states that the default value is 1 day. I don't know how are you getting 7

Comment: Neither do I!  That is the point.  The resources are coming back with `Cache-Control: max-age=604800` (7 days) which is definitely not the default.

Comment: @JohnWu You can always put a `<clear />` under `<staticContent>` as first child node to clear inherited settings. Also, I recommend you to [enable failed request tracing logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis#enable-failed-request-tracing) to see what happens. You can configure to collect data for `200 OK` responses ...

Comment: @JohnWu ... After the logs created open the log named something like `fr000001.xml` with Internet Explorer skip Compact View and search for `HeaderName="Cache-Control"` as you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQkce.png). If you can't see any `max-age=604800`, then you can suspect something on the network adds / replaces the header.